# calling same name function

Tags: c++, class, function, include, duplicates

Is it possible to call foo() function from Foo.cpp
without changing function name Foo::foo() to Foo::newfoo().

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.hpp"

class Foo {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Foo::foo\n";
    }
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "Foo::bar\n";
        foo();// need to call foo() function from foo.cpp not Foo::foo()
    }
};

int main () {
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Foo.hpp**

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP_INCLUDED
#define FOO_HPP_INCLUDED

void foo();

#endif // FOO_HPP_INCLUDED
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include <iostream>
void foo(){
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}
```

ps.sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Does this really illustrate the problem? As written, Foo.cpp only sees one definition of the name `foo`. The only conflict is inside the definition of `void Foo::foo()` in `main.cpp`. That's what the answers seem to be addressing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use fully qualified name of the free function.

```
::foo();
```

The `::` in front of the function name, tells the compiler to call the function by the name `foo()` that is in the global scope.
If the free function `foo()` *was* in some other namespace you need to use fully qualified name specifying the namespace.

```
namespacename::foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the free function `foo` is defined in some namespace `xyz`, then do this:

```
 xyz::foo();  //if foo is defined in xyz namespace
```

or else just do this:

```
::foo();     //if foo is defined in the global namespace
```

This one assumes `foo` is defined in the global namespace.

**It is better to use namespace for your implementation. Avoid polluting the global namespace.**